# Error en el último paso al firmar un PDF con certificado X509 usando iText7

Tags: c#, itext

Firmando un archivo PDF con iText7 recibo el error "System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'" en la siguiente línea:

```
signer1.SignDetached(pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

Mas detalles de la Excepción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien podría ayudarme para encontrar la causa?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       

      
        string RutaArchivo = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "pdf" + @"\Firmar." + "pdf";
        string RutaArchivoFDO = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "pdf" + @"\Firmar_FDObis." + "pdf";
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(RutaArchivo);

            FileStream privateKeyStream = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + "pdf" + @"\certificado." + "pfx",
                System.IO.FileMode.Open);
            Pkcs12Store pk12 = new Pkcs12Store(privateKeyStream, "1122".ToCharArray());
        privateKeyStream.Dispose();
      

        string alias = null;
        foreach (string tAlias in pk12.Aliases)
        {
            if (pk12.IsKeyEntry(tAlias))
            {
                alias = tAlias;
                break;
            }
        }
        var pk = pk12.GetKey(alias).Key;
        var ce = pk12.GetCertificateChain(alias);
        var chain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[ce.Length];
        for (int k = 0; k < ce.Length; ++k)
            chain[k] = ce[k].Certificate;

        // reader and stamper
        PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(RutaArchivo);
        FileStream fout = new FileStream(RutaArchivoFDO, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        StampingProperties properties = new StampingProperties();
        PdfSigner signer1 = new PdfSigner(reader1, fout, properties);
        // Create the signature appearance
        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(36, 648, 200, 100);
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance1 = signer1.GetSignatureAppearance();
        appearance1
                .SetReason("Pruebadefirma")
                .SetLocation("Miordenador")

                // Specify if the appearance before field is signed will be used
                // as a background for the signed field. The "false" value is the default value.
                .SetReuseAppearance(false)
                .SetPageRect(rect1)
                .SetPageNumber(1);
                signer1.SetFieldName("sig");

       
        IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-512");
      
            signer1.SignDetached(pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
      

    }
```

Comment: Por favor pon un fragmento más largo de la traza de error

Comment: Gracias Alfabravo, añadido.

Comment: He suprimido la parte inicial que abría el diálogo para elegir el certificado X509 puesto que no se emplea posteriormente. Empleo el .pfx. Aunque mi objetivo es realmente usar un certificado X509 para firmar el PDF directamente. Hasta ahora no he encontrado la forma de hacerlo sin pasar por exportarlo a PFX.